# Javascript multiple template replaces for insertAdjacentHTML

Tags: javascript, html

I currently have the following under a  to generate blocks of Divs based on 2 remote consts:

```
const images = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png",];

const text = ["txt1", "txt2","txt3", "txt4"]

var target = document.querySelector(".image-grid");

var template = "<div><label class=\"image-container\"><img src=\"~id~\"</label><div class=\"share-tray\"><a href=\"https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=~txtid~"><i class=\"fab fa-twitter\"></i></a></div></div>";

images.forEach(function(item) {
        target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", template.replace(/~id~/g, item));
```

This is working fine to place the image containers and images.
I want to be able to replace the ~txtid~ inside the template with text[i] (effectively) but a second replace doesn't seem to work. I can't really edit the consts as they serve other pages

Many thanks

Answer (score 3):

Change the regular expression to match *either* `~id~` or `~txtid~`, then use a replacer function to determine which was matched, and then use either the image or the text (using the iteration index).

You could also consider using a template literal instead of `\"` for all your `"`s.

```js
const images = ["images/1.png", "images/2.png", "images/3.png", ];
const text = ["txt1", "txt2", "txt3", "txt4"]

const target = document.querySelector(".image-grid");
const template = `<div><label class="image-container"><img src="~id~"</label><div class="share-tray"><a href="https://twitter.com/intent/tweet?text=~txtid~"><i class="fab fa-twitter"></i></a></div></div>`;

images.forEach((image, i) => {
  target.insertAdjacentHTML(
    "beforeend",
    template.replace(/~(id|txtid)~/g, (_, match) => match === 'id' ? image : text[i])
  );
});
console.log(target.innerHTML);
```

```html
<div class="image-grid">
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

```
images.forEach(function(item) {
replacedHTML = template.replace(/~txtid~/g, text[i]);
target.insertAdjacentHTML("beforeend", replacedHTML.replace(/~id~/g, item));
i = i + 1
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved by adding more information on what the code does and how it helps the OP.